# Plugin/Tool to detect JDBC Connection Lekage in recursive Loop

Tags: java, jdbc, connection

I want to know if there exist any plug-ins/tools to detect the open connection in the java code. I have found one jar but it's not checking the open connection inside the recursive loop (inside if loop if the connection is open). We are sure that our application contains some bug somewhere which cause conn leaks, but we cannot identify the class/method responsible for the leakage since the DAO class is more than 500. increased MaxConnection property to 400 but still no luck?

Comment: are you running a standalone java application or is it running inside an application server ?

Comment: It's running inside the application server. Added sample snippet of the code below

Comment: public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
SampleProjec dsExample = new SampleProjec();
Connection con = null;
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
int rowCount;
try {
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
con= dsExample.createConnection(); // Create multiple connection
String query = "select * from Employee";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
if (rs != null) {
rowCount = rs.getInt(1);
rs.close();
}
}
} finally {
con.close();
stmt.close();
}
}